# Why "first" or "any" aggregate functions are not commonly used in database engines?

Tags: sql, database

Some database engines like Microsoft Access supports `FIRST()` as an aggregate function and I was using it in cases I know the column will only have one value in the group.

Potentially, the database engine can optimise this as if it reaches any value it can mark this value as already calculated. So it is a surprise why this is not supported in for example Oracle or SQL Server, and more importantly, not in the SQL standard.

In practice, people uses `MIN()` or `MAX()` instead, but they all require

1. The data type underneath have natural ordering semantic and the ordering does matter for the user;
2. The database engine have to compare the intermediate value with the values in each rows

So this is not optimal in many cases.

Are there any specific reasons people don't want to allow `SELECT ANY(FIELD) ...`? (I could think of two variants: `ANY()` gives any value in the result set that the column is not null; `FIRST()` gives the column value for the first row in result set, or null if there is no rows)

Comment: In SQL Server 2012 and above there is `FIRST_VALUE` function that you may want to take a look at [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql).

Comment: Postgres, Oracle and DB2 also support `first_value` - which is part of the SQL standard. Alternatively the SQL standard's `min() keep (..)` would serve a similar purpose

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name `keep (...)` is Oracle specific, not standard SQL.

Comment: I am pretty sure that `FIRST_VALUE` is not in the standard docs. Moreover, `FIRST_VALUE` is a window function only. So this is not an alternative to `MIN` or `MAX`. MySQL features `ANY_VALUE`, which does the job and is a much better Name at that, as `FIRST` suggests an order which is not present. As far as I know, the standard doesn't contain any aggregate function like this, but then, this is a function that would hardly be needed in a standard-compliant DBMS either.

Comment: Another concern is that `FIRST_VALUE` is not an aggregate function, it is not working with grouping, as I can see so far (I didn't use it before, just checked the documents today). If my understand is wrong please give me an example that is using this in a grouping SQL.

Answer (score 4):

**Regarding `first`/`last`**

The syntax supported by Microsoft Access SQL doesn't make sense in standard SQL:

```
SELECT  
       First(LastName) as First,
       Last(LastName) as Last
  FROM Employees
```

([source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/first-last-functions-microsoft-access-sql))

In Standard SQL, grouping takes places before sorting. Normally, groups are not sorted. That means, it is undefined which row comes first/last. Standard SQL generally aims to avoid constructs that have nondeterministic behaviour (exceptions exist).

Standard SQL offers to  so-called *ordered set functions* that accept an `within group (order by...)` clause to establish an order in a group prior to aggregation:

```
SELECT
        PERCENTILE_DISC(0.5) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY val)
  FROM ...
```

The range for the argument of `percentile_disc` is `0` to `1` whereas `0` is the first result and `1` the last. `0.5` is the *median* (this is the common use-case for `percentile_disc`).

However, standard SQL does not offer `first`/`last` as ordered set function, but `percentile_disc` with an argument of `0` is basically first, while the value `1` would basically give you the last result.

The more common SQL way to obtain the first/last value is to use a top-n query:

```
SELECT LastName
  FROM Employees
 ORDER BY ...
 FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Fetching first and last value in one go is a little bit awkward.

Other than that, standard SQL also offers the window functions `first_value` and `last_value` to pick those values out of a *partition* without grouping.

**Regarding `any`**

Standard SQL has an aggregate function `any` but for a different use case. Again, what you (MS Access SQL) suggest for any gives you a non-deterministic result, which is not what standard SQL encourages.

The standard SQL function `any` returns a boolean that is true if *any* of the conditions is true. It is best used in `having` clauses:

```
SELECT
       *
  FROM ..
 GROUP BY ...
HAVING ANY(<condition>)
```

This remove all *groups* where no `<condition>` evaluates to *true*.

References:

- Slides regarding `WITHIN GROUP`: https://www.slideshare.net/MarkusWinand/modern-sql/105
- Blog post on the `every` function (which is similar to `any`): https://blog.jooq.org/2014/12/18/a-true-sql-gem-you-didnt-know-yet-the-every-aggregate-function/

Comment: Being non-deterministic could be bad; but if it is what people wanted, why shouldn't it be supported? `Order by rand()` for example is an explicit way to express a random order, but much less efficient with no order at all and leave some behaviours being non-deterministic.

Comment: @EarthEngine I didn't say non-determinisitc behaviour is bad per se, it is just avoided in standard SQL as a default behaviour. Standard SQL does not even provide a random function, but it provides TABLESAMPLE, which just takes a random sample from a table. Also: it allows using ROW_NUMBER() without ORDER BY in the WHERE clause as extra feature. It is just that the default should not be non-deterministic.

Comment: I need more answers like this, that actually explain real life SQL to me.

Answer (score 2):

`FIRST` (or better `ANY_VALUE` as MySQL calls the function) is not in the SQL standard. This is probably because it is hardly needed in a standard-compliant DBMS.

You say you use `FIRST` *"in cases I know the column will only have one value in the Group"*. In a well-built database such a case should hardly ever occur. Maybe you are rather using it, because MS Access (and several other DBMS) violate the standard when it comes to aggregation with a `GROUP BY` clause. An example:

```
select department_id, d.department_name, count(*) as num_employees
from employees e
join departments d using (department_id)
group by d.department_id;
```

You may want to use `FIRST(d.department_name)` here, because you know that per `department_id` there will be just one `department_name` of course. But so does the DBMS (or better: it should!). In standard SQL the above query is valid, because the `department_name` is functionally dependent on the `department_id`. No need hence for a `FIRST` or `ANY_VALUE` function.

MySQL introduced `ANY_VALUE` mainly in order to deal with cases where the DBMS fails to detect the functional dependency, but again these cases should be extremely rare. I like the function, because it gives you the opportunity to say "I don't care which", e.g. give me the departments and one leader per department (i.e. in case there are two department leaders: one of them arbitrarily chosen). But well, I guess in the standard comittee they decided that `MIN` or `MAX` would serve the purpose in such rare cases, too.

Comment: I understand that functional dependency can be used to detect potential optimisations. However, sometimes (especially for temp tables) tables are not indicated to have functional dependency and this can happen in all applications (you don't want to introduce foreign keys and indexes for your temp tables in many cases). So this scenario is still there.

Comment: @Earth Engine: Good point. In my twenty five years of working with databases, though, I have never had to create a temporary table in any code.

Comment: Also, I have to say that the example SQL in your text is not valid. In a group function, you have to either put `d.department_name` inside an aggregate function like `MIN(d.department_name)`, or put `d.department_name` in the `group by` clause. But your point is still valid: a good database engine (working on a good designed schema) shall know that `d.department_name` have only one value in the group.

Comment: @Earth Engine: No. The query is valid according to the SQL standard. It is MS Access that forces you to either aggregate by a column or put it in `GROUP BY`. The name is functionally dependent on the ID, so there is no need to in a standard-compliant DBMS. MS Access violates the standard here.

Answer (score 2):

[My research](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/11458) has shown that at least these SQL dialects support `ANY_VALUE()` as aggregate functions (and often also window functions):

- [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aggregate_functions#any_value)
- [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_any-value)
- [Oracle 21c](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/ANY_VALUE.html#GUID-A3C47D5E-B145-40B2-93D2-CA3BA65C2D81)
- [Redshift](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ANY_VALUE.html)
- [SingleStore (MemSQL)](https://docs.singlestore.com/v7.3/reference/sql-reference/aggregate-functions/any_value/)
- [Snowflake](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/any_value.html)

And this one supports `FIRST_VALUE` and `LAST_VALUE`, which are similar:

- [HANA](https://help.sap.com/viewer/4fe29514fd584807ac9f2a04f6754767/2.0.04/en-US/034b17549b5d4b7d913e2c2770eea45b.html)

It's not as widespread as it could be, but not completely unheard of, either.